# Parsing XML file with IXMLDocument in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi-10.3-rio

In Delphi 10 Rio, I use `IXMLDocument` to parse an XML file.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?><AWXML><ACTION>RECUP<RETOUR>OK</RETOUR><CRITERE><COMPTE></COMPTE><REGROUPEME></REGROUPEME><bas01></bas01></CRITERE><RUBRIQUE><DOC_NOM>TEST110 &#128;</DOC_NOM>
```

When I do

```pascal
NomDoc := Node2.ChildNodes['DOC_NOM'].Text;
```

`NomDoc` is `'TEST110 ?'`, but it should be `'TEST110 €'`.

Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: i search how replace &#128 in character "€" ?

Comment: Please edit your question instead of adding comment!

Comment: You specify ISO8859-1 but this lacks the euro symbol. See https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/CEI_8859-1 Pick another encoding having the euro symbol. In Unicode, it is &#8364.

Answer (score 1):

The `Encoding` attribute in the XML's prolog specifies the byte encoding of the XML itself, not the charset that the XML's content is to be interpreted in. XML content is always interpreted in Unicode only. Thus `&#128;` represents Unicode codepoint [U+0080](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0080/index.htm), which is a C1 control character that is "only valid in certain contexts in XML 1.0 documents, and whose usage is restricted and highly discouraged."

If you want to use a Euro character, Unicode codepoint [U+20AC](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/20AC/index.htm), in an XML document, you must use either `&#8364;` or `&#x20AC;` instead, regardless of the `Encoding` specified.